# Как залить локальную версию git на GITHub

Tags: git, github

привет...Создал у себя локальный Git- проект...
Есть созданный на GitHub branch который назыв. master..
Но получаю ошибку...В чем проблема? 
Перед тем не выкачивал себе проэкт.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Может стоит "склонировать" проект с гитхаба на локаль, далее туда перенести ваш локальный проект (без папки .git), и сделать:

    1) git add .
    2) git commit -m 'any comment'
    3) git push origin master

Comment: SourceTree http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ может ускорить процесс

Comment: Вы локально создали git репозиторий, а на github'е уже что-то есть, и вы пытаетесь одну историю изменений залить в совершенно другую? У вас ничего не получится. И не стоит репозиторий называть `master`, будете путаться ещё больше, `master` это обычно основная ветка.

Answer (score 1):

`git pull --rebase` не работает, потому что вы явно не указываете remote. Нужно

```
git pull --rebase mster master
```

или ещё лучше remote называть как-то типа origin или upstream:

```
git remote add origin git@...
```

и потом

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```